# Write simple converter

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this Class:

```
public class MyData
{
   public static int Total Files;
   public static int Total FilesFinished;
}
```

And I have simple `Progress-Bar` that calculate its `Value` this way:

```
double value = ((double)MyData.FilesFinished / MyData.Files) * 100;
```

And update my `Label` using simple `Timer`:

```
Label name="lblPercentage" />

lblPercentage.Content = value;
```

Now I want to use `Converter` instead of updating my `Label` via code behind.

So I have this class (not implemented yet):

```
public class TotalFilesToTotalPercentageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Inside my `Window.Resource` I have this:

```
<Convertors:TotalFilesToTotalPercentageConverter  x:Key="FilesToPercentageConverter "/>
```

And this is what I have try inside my `Label`:

```
 Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FilesToPercentageConverter}}"
```

So my problem is that I try to see if my `TotalFilesToTotalPercentageConverter` class is responding via the debugger and it seems not, nothing happening.

What did I do wrong?

**Update**

I forget to mention that my `TotalFilesToTotalPercentageConverter` `class` in inside `Converter` folder under `Utils` folder under `Classes` folder

Comment: It's unclear why you think your Binding Path would do anything sensible. Please read up about the basics in [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview)

Comment: I update my question and remove this path and still nothing

Comment: Removing the Path is not enough. Before trying to use it you should understand the basic about data binding.

Comment: Well, after read this article i try to admit that i am more confused and still dont know how to solve it, can i have short code example please ?

Comment: And what you suppose should be passed in converter if you didn't specify `Path` of binding? Your binding's target will be updated on changes of bound value and currently it is entire view-model. Your view-model must expose `TotalFilesFinished` **property** that should be updated raising `PropertyChanged` event. And then write `Path=TotalFilesFinished` in the binding.

Comment: @Maxim If you don't set Path, the source object (held by the element's DataContext) is passed to the converter. However, that's certainly not what OP is intending to do.

Comment: @Clemens I wrote the same thing. But yes I had to write `DataContext` instead of view-model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the `Content` property to a source property for your `Convert` method to be invoked. Converters only work with data bindings.

This means that instead of setting the `Content` property of the `Label` in the code-behind like this:

```
lblPercentage.Content = value;
```

You should set a source property of a view model that you then bind the `Content` property of the `Label` to:

```
Content="{Binding Path=YourValueProperty, Converter={StaticResource FilesToPercentageConverter}}"
```

Set the `DataContext` of your view to an instance of your view model class:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

The view model class needs to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the source property (`YourValueProperty`).